# How to enforce that all traffic from iOS app goes through VPN?

Tags: ios, vpn, privacy

I need to make sure that one of the apps I use can only use internet traffic that goes through VPN.

How, as a non-corporate user, can I achieve that? Can per-app VPN settings enabled with a custom profile help with that? Is it the best possible way?

My first thoughts are:

- **MDM profile-defined per-app VPN**. If it is a way to go, what are the key pieces of the setup I need?
  (I want to be sure that profile-defined per-app VPN will help with my problem; also that a manually-created profile will work just as well as a "enterprise tool-generated" one).
- **Workflow app or a similar tool**. Is there any which is able to initiate VPN connection and wait until connection is established?
- **"Connect on demand" always-on VPN**: I tried it, but it allows some of the app's traffic to skip VPN when switching from wifi to mobile data or vice versa, for the periods when VPN is reconnecting. Such non-VPN traffic for the app is what I want to avoid completely.

Of course I'm fine to wait for establishing connection every time I switch to the app if any of the methods require that.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, you may want to read Apple's documentation on Per App VPN: help.apple.com/deployment/ios/#/apdfbf6f529b. The article states that in order to use Per App VPN, an app must be managed by MDM (Mobile Device Management) and use standard networking APIs, that is, the device must be managed in a corporate environment, which is not your case (you mention that you a non-corporate user). A solution would be to create a MDM profile yourself.

Comment: If you want to go to the trouble of creating an MDM profile yourself, this is a (rather long) guide to do it: https://medium.com/developerinsider/how-to-create-a-verified-ios-mobile-device-management-mdm-profile-9d6739b92cc1

Comment: @jaume Thanks, I've seen the guide mentioned in one of the earlier questions at SE. The questions still remain: will manually-created MDM profile help me with what I need?

Comment: I don't see why not, I'd say a manually-created MDM profile acts on the device in the same way an MDM profile created by an enterprise tool like MobileIron would. But I don't have first-hand experience, so I can't give you a definitive answer. Hopefully someone who has can chime in. I'd recommend that you edit your question to make it clear that you know that a MDM profile is necessary and you want to be sure that a manually-created profile will work just as well as a "enterprise tool-generated" one.

Comment: Thanks, tried to expand my question to better reflect what aspects are still unclear for me in the options I can see.

Comment: @wassrubleff Take a look here → https://developer.apple.com/enterprise/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf

Comment: @JBis Does "How to configure" answers the question whether per-app VPN will guarantee that absolutely no traffic from the app will skip VPN?

Comment: @wassrubleff I think so. But your question seems to be more about creating one.

Comment: My question is "how to enforce"? "To make sure that app can ONLY use traffic going thru VPN".

Comment: @wassrubleff If its possible, and according to the documentation it is, then the answer there should solve the issue.

Comment: @jaume Am I reading the docs from Apple correctly that I can only set up per-app VPN for the app I developed, not for a third-party app from AppStore? The "App to Per App VPN" section requires DesignatedRequirement and SigningIdentifier, both of which seems to be available only for app developer.

Comment: @jbis Please also see the question in my previous comment here.